# I don't want lollipop for moto E(1st gen)

Tags: motorola-moto-e

In my mobile there very less space my phone is hanged and it makes to irration to me.
I decided to back for kik Kate 
Plz solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to downgrad to Android 4.4.4 from Lollipop.
There is a guide over at XDA developers which does exactly what you want.
Just follow the steps as described there:
[Downgrade Moto E Android 5.0.2 to Stock 4.4.4](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e/general/video-tutorial-downgrade-moto-e-android-t3032738)

Credits for this instructions go to meakshay_mishra @ xda

1. Download Stock 4.4.4
2. Download mfastboot.
3. Download ADB. ( Download Links are in video description)

Now flash Stock 4.4.4 using adb.
commands :

> mfastboot flash partition gpt.bin
>
> mfastboot flash motoboot motoboot.img
>
> mfastboot flash logo logo.bin
>
> mfastboot flash boot boot.img
>
> mfastboot flash recovery recovery.img
>
> mfastboot.exe flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0
>
> mfastboot.exe flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1
>
> mfastboot.exe flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2
>
> mfastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin
>
> mfastboot erase modemst1
>
> mfastboot erase modemst2
>
> mfastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn
>
> mfastboot erase cache
>
> mfastboot erase userdata
>
> mfastboot reboot